# Remove blank rows and columns of an array inside a keras Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a keras model, which takes a 10x10x1 array as input. For example:

```
array = np.array([
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
])
```

This array represents the number '5'

[image]

What I want to do is, to remove all the 'blank' (pixel value of 0) rows and columns.
The resultant array would have a shape of 5x2x1,

```
array = np.array([
[[1],[1]],
[[1],[0]],
[[1],[1]],
[[0],[1]],
[[1],[1]]
])
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

I want to do this in a keras model, as a layer, so it has to be done with `tensorflow.keras.backend`.
It can be as a `Lambda` layer, like this:

```
def remove_blank(x):
   ...
   return x_

model.add(Lambda(remove_blank))
```

Also, this function should be able to do this with RGB images too, meaning a 3D array of shape (HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3).

An example of RGB image would be:

```
array = np.array([
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
], dtype='float')
```

[image]

The function should remove the rows and columns which contain only black pixels and transform this image to this:

```
array = np.array([
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
[[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
[[0,0,0],[1,1,1]],
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
], dtype='float')
```

[image]

Comment: But your resulting array still contains "(pixel value of 0)" ;)

Comment: @AloneTogether yes, but no column or row contains all zeros.

Comment: @AloneTogether The same applies for RGB images

Comment: @AloneTogether if the mean of a row or column is 0, then it should eliminated. But how to do it inside a keras model

Comment: what if you have a batch size > 1 and the remove_blank method returns a tensor with a different shape for each sample in the batch?

Comment: @AloneTogether I will use a `tf.keras.layers.Resizing()` layer to resize it to a fixed shape

Comment: then I will use the `Resizing` layer right after removing all the blank rows and columns inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, but note that iterating over a tensor in `graph` mode will not work, so rather use `tf.while_loop` for a `batch_size` > 1. If `batch_size` = 1, you do not need any loop:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

five = tf.constant([
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
], dtype=tf.float32)

eight = tf.constant([
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
], dtype=tf.float32)

def remove_blank(t):
  ragged = []
  for i in tf.range(tf.shape(t)[0]):
    tensor = tf.expand_dims(t[i, :, :, 0], axis=0)
    x = tf.where(tf.not_equal(tensor, 0.0))
    _min = tf.reduce_min(x, axis=0)
    _max = tf.reduce_max(x, axis=0)
    col_range = tf.range(_min[1], _max[1] + 1)
    row_range = tf.range(_min[2], _max[2] + 1)

    i = tf.repeat(col_range, repeats=tf.shape(row_range)[0])
    j = tf.tile(row_range, multiples=[tf.shape(col_range)[0]])
    b = tf.zeros(tf.shape(i)[0], dtype=tf.int64)

    z = tf.gather_nd(tensor, tf.transpose(tf.stack([b, i, j])))
    z = tf.reshape(z, (tf.shape(tf.unique(x[:, 1])[0])[0], tf.shape(tf.unique(x[:, 2])[0])[0], tf.shape(t)[-1]))
    ragged.append(z)
  return tf.ragged.stack(ragged)

x = tf.stack([five, eight])

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(remove_blank))
output = model(x)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax1 = f.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(122)
ax1.imshow(five[:, :, 0], cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(eight[:, :, 0], cmap='gray')

f1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = f1.add_subplot(122)
ax1.imshow(output[0].to_tensor()[:, :, 0], cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(output[1].to_tensor()[:, :, 0], cmap='gray')
```

[image]
[image]

You will have to resize the images to a uniform size when training your model. I will leave it to you to figure out how to extend this method for `RGB` images ;)

#### Update 1:

Here is an example of the method integrated into a `Keras` model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

five = tf.constant([
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
], dtype=tf.float32)

eight = tf.constant([
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
], dtype=tf.float32)

def remove_blank(t):
  def _remove_blank(i0, v, t):
    tensor = tf.expand_dims(t[i0, :, :, 0], axis=0)
    x = tf.where(tf.not_equal(tensor, 0.0))
    _min = tf.reduce_min(x, axis=0)
    _max = tf.reduce_max(x, axis=0)
    col_range = tf.range(_min[1], _max[1] + 1)
    row_range = tf.range(_min[2], _max[2] + 1)

    i = tf.repeat(col_range, repeats=tf.shape(row_range)[0])
    j = tf.tile(row_range, multiples=[tf.shape(col_range)[0]])
    b = tf.zeros(tf.shape(i)[0], dtype=tf.int64)

    z = tf.gather_nd(tensor, tf.transpose(tf.stack([b, i, j])))
    z = tf.reshape(z, (tf.shape(tf.unique(x[:, 1])[0])[0], tf.shape(tf.unique(x[:, 2])[0])[0], tf.shape(t)[-1]))
    z = tf.expand_dims(tf.image.resize(z, [5, 2]), axis=0)

    h = tf.range(tf.shape(z)[1], dtype=tf.int32)
    ij = tf.expand_dims(tf.stack([tf.repeat([i0], repeats=tf.shape(h)[0]), h], axis=-1), axis=0)
    v = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(v, ij, z)

    return tf.add(i0, 1), v, t

  i0 = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
  v = tf.zeros((tf.shape(t)[0], 5, 2, 1))
  while_condition = lambda i0, v, t: tf.less(i0, tf.shape(t)[0])
  _, v, _ = tf.while_loop(while_condition, _remove_blank, loop_vars=(i0, v, t))
  return v

batch_size = 2
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((10, 10, 1))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(remove_blank)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

y = tf.random.normal((2, 5, 2, 1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=2, epochs=4)
```

```
Epoch 1/4
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 860ms/step - loss: 1.1193
Epoch 2/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 1.1193
Epoch 3/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 1.1193
Epoch 4/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 1.1193
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f11b0350510>
```

The solution for `RGB` images looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

five = tf.constant([
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
], dtype=tf.float32)

def _remove_blank(i, t, channel):
    tensor = tf.expand_dims(t[i, :, :, channel], axis=0)
    x = tf.where(tf.not_equal(tensor, 0.0))
    _min = tf.reduce_min(x, axis=0)
    _max = tf.reduce_max(x, axis=0)
    col_range = tf.range(_min[1], _max[1] + 1)
    row_range = tf.range(_min[2], _max[2] + 1)

    i = tf.repeat(col_range, repeats=tf.shape(row_range)[0])
    j = tf.tile(row_range, multiples=[tf.shape(col_range)[0]])
    b = tf.zeros(tf.shape(i)[0], dtype=tf.int64)

    z = tf.gather_nd(tensor, tf.transpose(tf.stack([b, i, j])))
    z = tf.reshape(z, (tf.shape(tf.unique(x[:, 1])[0])[0], tf.shape(tf.unique(x[:, 2])[0])[0], 1))
    return z

def remove_blank(t):
  ragged = []
  for i in tf.range(tf.shape(t)[0]): 
    z = tf.concat([_remove_blank(i, t, channel=0), _remove_blank(i, t, channel=1), _remove_blank(i, t, channel=2)], axis = -1)
    ragged.append(z)
  return tf.ragged.stack(ragged)

x = tf.expand_dims(five, axis=0)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(remove_blank))
output = model(x)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax1 = f.add_subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(five)

f1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(output[0].to_tensor())
```

Comment: Bang! Added method working with Keras! @MushfiratMohaimin

Comment: Any way you can make this work with RGB images?

Comment: But remember I wrote: ” I will leave it to you to figure out how to extend this method for RGB images ;)”

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I'm struggling with doing that, so I asked.

Comment: If you post a question with a clear example . Sure

Comment: I have added an example, check it out.